# Serialized XML is nested from auto-generated Java classes

Tags: xml, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jackson-dataformat-xml

Given a `.xsd` file, I had the strategy to use a Maven tool to generate Java classes from this, and then use Jackson to serialize the data.

I'm using:

- `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.3` to generate the Java classes
- `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper` (2.9.2) with `new JaxbAnnotationModule()` to serialize

Example of generated code:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<TLocalizedString> title;
```

Example of usage:

```
TLocalizedString tls = new TLocalizedString();
tls.setValue( string );
tls.setLocale( LOCALE );
item.getTitle().add( tls );
```

We are getting:

```
<item ....>
    <title>
        <title locale="en_US">The Title</title>
    </title>
```

What we expected:

```
<item ....>
    <title locale="en_US">The Title</title>
```

In other words the XML is coming out nested.

Is this something that should be controlled:

- In the code at point of usage?
- In the config for the Jackson serializer?
- In the code generation via config or generation flags?
- In the code generation via `.xsd` changes?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. I had seen a lot of examples using this config, but had no idea what it was actually doing. It was this [bug report](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/156) which gave me the clue, via the phrase

> wrapper element for Lists

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper( false ); // This prevents unnecessary nesting of XML elements
```